# Is it possible to show (a link to) List Item in Task created by Site Workflow

Tags: workflow

I've created a site workflow build around managing documents from document library. But the tasks created from a collect data and assign actions don't make reference to the list item ie the document. The document is making use of a custom content-type.

How can I include a link to the document or show information about the list item in the workflow task?

Have I created the wrong type of workflow; should it have been a list workflow or a reusable workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should have made it a list or reusable workflow.  Site workflows are meant to operate without a dependancy on list or library items.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335710.aspx):

> Site workflows release workflow developers from requiring a list item
>   or document item to run workflows against. This is useful for when the
>   process that the workflow is implementing does not start as a result
>   of a list item or document.

Comment: Thanks - I feel like crying as I will now have to recreate the whole thing again. It's been very painful mapping data that has been collected to update the list item.